# How to make my log sync bucket persistent in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-logging

I am storing GCP's cloud logging in a log bucket, but there is a limit to the storage period.
I would like to store the log bucket permanently in another bucket as a backup, is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the logs [up to 10 years](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods) in a custom log bucket.

If you need more, you can [export the logs to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) and archive them.

If you need query capability beyond 10 years, you can export the logs to BigQuery